# MVC @Html.DisplayForModel() different views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've just started to learn MVC.

I know that you can create a strongly typed view in Shared/DisplayTemplates, then after returning a list from the controller, you can do @Html.DisplayForModel() and it will use this as a template for the entire list.

However, what if I don't always want the model to be built in the way I've specified in this DisplayTemplate?  How can I create different display templates?

The obvious way seems to be to create a template for each object, then do something like...

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x, "AlternativeTemplate")
}
```

..but as you've now got the foreach, it doesn't seem as elegant.

Comment: Not at a pc with VS installed, but if couldn't you do away with that for each with a little linq `Model.ToList().ForEach(m => Html.DisplayFor(x => x, "AltTemplate"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you can use the DisplayForModel overload that takes a String param for the template name. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430910(v=vs.98).aspx

You just have to have the template defined under Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates with the exact name as given in the String.